# May Service annotated classes contain SQL/HQL in spring framework?

Tags: java, spring

i examine lots of samples but i didn't find an adequate solution for this.
Some documents say "Ideally your business logic layer shouldn’t know there is a database. It shouldn’t know about connection strings or SQL."

I found some samples which locate the business logic to @Service annotated classes but they use SQL/HQL in @Service methods.

What should be the ideal usage? If we want to change database or persistence technology should we change only @Repository annotated classes or both of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer putting all persistence-related stuff (i.e. queries, and everything dealing with JDBC, JPA or Hibernate) in a DAO layer, and have the service layer rely on this DAO layer for persistence-related stuff.

But the main goal is not to be able to change the persistence technology without affecting the service layer. Although that could be possible if you switch from Hibernate to JPA, for example, it wouldn't be if you switch from JPA to JDBC, for example. The reasons are that

- JPA automatically persists all the changes made to entities without any need for update database queries , whereas JDBC doesn't, and thus needs additional update queries
- JPA lazy-loads association between entities, whereas JDBC doesn't
- ...

So changing the persistence technology will affect the service layer, even if all the persistence stuff is isolated in DAOs.

The main advantages of this decoupling, IMHO are

- clearer responsibilities for each class. It avois mixing persistence-related code with business logic code.
- testability: you can easily test your service layer by mocking the DAO layer. You can easily test the DAO layer because all it does is executing queries over the database.

Answer (score 2):

In your service methods you shouldn't use any SQL/HQL syntax or any database work. All of them should be in DAO layer which are annotated as @Repository. You should just call them from your service methods. In this way, you can easily change your db in future. Otherwise, it would have too much burden

Comment: Any of spring documentation contains a description like you did? I didn't find an official explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally your business logic deals with or consists of objects that model the domain. It shouldn't be aware of the issues of persistence etc. . That's what O/R-Mapper like hibernate are all about. The business logic demands required objects, based on domain attributes (like Employee name, last month's revenue ...).

The persistence layer should be able to translate the business demands into SQL/HQL/Service calls or whatever the used technology requires. Therefore the business logic layer only changes when the business logic changes.

That would be the goal in an ideal world, but in reality it won't work for non-trivial problems. You can't avoid some degree of coupling. But as @JB Nizet said, it pays off to reduce the coupling to a reasonable amount. Using TDD and adhering to OO principles like SRP will help you get there.